# Help with a 3-body problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, classical-mechanics

If I have three particles with masses $ m_1, m_2, m_3$ with their respective position vectors $ x_1, x _2, x_3 $ and their speeds $ v_1, v_2, v_3 $ how could I find a parametric function that would tell me their positions for all future times? I would be very thankful if anyone could actually input values into the position vectors and speeds and masses to find functions that I could actually plot so as to get a better grasp over this problem. You can choose any values you want to make it more convenient or easy to solve if you wish.
Mathematicians of Math Stack Exchange, I have searched for a clear example of a solution to this problem all over the internet, I really hope you can help me. Thank you very much for anything you can give me.

Comment: Use newtons law of gravitation to set up the system of equations. It is a pretty well studied problem. I.e a quick search on Google and even on here will bring you fortune :)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem You're not going to find a closed-form solution for the general problem in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Wish I could help. I'm having enough trouble with a $2$-body problem myself...

Comment: The one body I have requires a lot of maintenance...

Comment: @copper.hat:  boy, ain't that the truth! Happy Holidays!

Comment: Re. the title:  *everybody* needs help with three body problem, as the comments and answer(s) demonstrate!

Comment: @RobertLewis: Happy Holidays to you too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a notorious problem with no nice solutions, except some nice special cases. It behaves chaotically with respect to the initial conditions.

There's a book about it available online for free: http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/volume/missiondesign/KoLoMaRo_DMissionBook_2011-04-25.pdf

Comment: You just beat me to it. I'd add this reference: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Three_body_problem

Comment: Thanks, I thought that when they said the n-body problem had been solved it implied it would also have nice solutions. Too bad differential equations are such a mess.